# P/Invoke SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail returning 1784

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, pinvoke

I am currently trying to P/Invoke to HID (in Unity (so using .Net 2.0)).
However, when calling SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail, it is returning error code 1784.

MIND: this is on the 2nd call, since the first call should (and does) return error 122, and set the buffer size needed.

```
..Replaced With Full Source Below..
```

USED STRUCTS:

```
..Replaced With Full Source Below..
```

DETAIL_DATA is not used at the moment, sice I saw I should use an IntPtr for that instead.

How can I get rid of my Error 1784 and get/iterate my device-paths?
Also, I read I should use "null", in stead of dData, but this errors as well (cannot convert null to DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA)

EDIT: FULL SOURCE

DebugInput.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using Assets;

public class DebugInput : MonoBehaviour {
    static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F3))
        {
            Debug.Log("Checking");
            WindowsHID hid = new WindowsHID();
            Guid gHid = hid.HIDGuid; // "4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030"
            Debug.Log(gHid);
            IntPtr hDevInfo = hid.GetClassDevs(gHid); // 475463200L
            if (hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                Debug.Log("INTPTR RETREIVED");
                WindowsHID.DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA diData = new WindowsHID.DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
                diData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(diData); // 32


                Boolean Check = false;
                uint enumerator = 0;
                Check = hid.SetupInterfaces(hDevInfo, IntPtr.Zero, ref gHid, enumerator, ref diData); // Check = True, hDevInfo = 475463200L, diData.reserved = 653193792L (hDevInfo changes on each rebuild)
                uint sizeNeeded;
                WindowsHID.DEVINFO_DATA dData = new WindowsHID.DEVINFO_DATA();
                dData.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(dData); // 32u

                bool result3 = WindowsHID.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, diData, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out sizeNeeded, dData); // sizeNeeded becomes 180u
                if (!result3)
                {
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // Expecting error 122, since we are only setting SizeNeeded Here (getting error 122)
                    Debug.Log(error);
                }
                IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)sizeNeeded); // 4640736L

                try
                {
                    uint size = sizeNeeded; // 180u
                    Marshal.WriteInt32(DeviceInterfaceDetailData, (int)size); // DevinceInterfaceDetailData doesnt change (IS THIS LINE NEEDED?)
                    bool result4 = WindowsHID.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, diData, DeviceInterfaceDetailData, size, out sizeNeeded, dData);
                    if (!result4)
                    {
                        int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // GETTING ERROR 1784???
                        Debug.Log(error);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(DeviceInterfaceDetailData);
                }                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("INVALID GUID");
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

WindowsHID.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;

namespace Assets
{
    public class WindowsHID
    {
        /// <summary>Used in SetupDiClassDevs to get devices present in the system</summary>
        protected const int DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x02;
        /// <summary>Used in SetupDiClassDevs to get device interface details</summary>
        protected const int DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x10;
        protected const int DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x04;
        static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);
        public WindowsHID()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides Info About a Single USB-Device
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
        {
            public Int32 cbSize;
            public Guid interfaceClassGuid;
            public Int32 flags;
            public UIntPtr reserved;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto, Pack=1)]
        public struct DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public char DevicePath;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DEVINFO_DATA
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public Guid classGuid;
            public uint devInst;
            public IntPtr reserved;
        }        

        #region P/Invoke
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Windows GUID for the HID class Devices
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="guid"></param>
        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        protected static extern void HidD_GetHidGuid(out Guid guid);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ClassGuid"></param>
        /// <param name="Enumerator"></param>
        /// <param name="hwndParent"></param>
        /// <param name="Flags"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string Enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hDevInfo"></param>
        /// <param name="devInfo"></param>
        /// <param name="interfaceClassGuid"></param>
        /// <param name="memberIndex"></param>
        /// <param name="deviceInterfaceData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        protected static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(IntPtr hDevInfo, int devInfo, ref Guid interfaceClassGuid, uint memberIndex, ref DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hDevInfo"></param>
        /// <param name="deviceInterfaceData"></param>
        /// <param name="deviceInterfaceDetailData"></param>
        /// <param name="deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize"></param>
        /// <param name="requiredSize"></param>
        /// <param name="deviceInfoData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr hDevInfo, DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData, IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData, uint deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, out uint requiredSize, DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData);
        #endregion

        public Guid HIDGuid
        {
            get
            {
                Guid gHid;
                HidD_GetHidGuid(out gHid);
                return gHid;
            }
        }

        public IntPtr GetClassDevs(Guid gHid)
        {
            return SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref gHid, null, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);// | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
        }

        public Boolean SetupInterfaces(IntPtr hDevInfo, IntPtr devInfo, ref Guid interfaceClassGuid, uint memberIndex, ref DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData)
        {
            Boolean res = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, 0, ref interfaceClassGuid, memberIndex, ref deviceInterfaceData);
            int a = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            return res;
        }    

        public Boolean SetupInterfaceDetail(IntPtr hDevInfo, DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterfaceData, IntPtr deviceInterfaceDetailData, uint deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, out uint requiredSize, DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData)
        {
            Boolean a = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, deviceInterfaceData, deviceInterfaceDetailData, deviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, out requiredSize, deviceInfoData);
            int b = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DevicePath should be an IntPtr (or a string)

Comment: I'm currently not using that struct.. Instead I'm using IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)sizeNeeded); since i read that I should "delete" that struct and use an IntPtr instead

Comment: You need to provide a full repro, your code is very partial (would take a while to redefine all what you're using)

Comment: added full source (I know its ugly at the moment, but I want to be able to iterate through and get my DevicePaths before I work on the Object-Oriented part a bit more)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace the following line:

```
Marshal.WriteInt32(DeviceInterfaceDetailData, (int)size);
```

By

```
Marshal.WriteInt32(DeviceInterfaceDetailData, IntPtr.Size == 8 ? 8 : 6);
```

Because SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail  documentation explicitely states this:

> The caller must set DeviceInterfaceDetailData.cbSize to
>   sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA) before calling this function.
>   The cbSize member always contains the size of the fixed part of the
>   data structure, not a size reflecting the variable-length string at
>   the end.

`sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)` depends on the process bitness, it's 6 with an X86 process (byte packing + 1 char, auto -> unicode -> 4 + 2*1) and 8 with an X64 process (8 bytes packing anyway).

Also note your definition of SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail should use ref parameters for structures. Once you have changed all that you can get the device path like this:

```
string devicePath = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(DeviceInterfaceDetailData + 4);
```

(PtrToStringAuto because you choose Auto charset on your p/invoke definitions)

Comment: Dang it, I even had that in there when using the struct xD
It seems to work, all though I can't really see how to get the (string)DevicePath from the IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData..
Do U mind showing how to do it using the Struct DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA?

Comment: Also, does this mean the AllocHGlobal isnt needed?

Comment: Ah now I see how other people are doing it.. 

For others that are stuck:

They're adding SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail twice, once with an IntPtr, and once with the DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA, so that they can first call it with IntPtr.Zero (to get the needed size) and then call it using the struct, to get the device-path..

Thx for the help

Comment: Only now all paths seem to be "\\"  :S

Comment: Yes, you do need to allocate and free the memory like you do. The string is Unicode (because you use Auto for p/invoke defs, it will be Unicode). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Actually I changed it to use the struct now, since PtrToStringAuto only returned "\b". Also, using Encoding.GetBytes() on the string DevicePath still only returns 2 bytes (the \ and the terminating 0).. Will try changing Auto in the def though

Comment: It works fine for me, w/o the struct. You can look at the memory pointed by DeviceInterfaceDetailData to check if the string is ansi or unicode. Encoding.GetBytes() is irrelevant here.

Comment: What I meant was that I was using the struct, and afterwards using 
byte[] code = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(detailData.DevicePath);
byte[] uni = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(detailData.DevicePath);
Where both were turning into a 2-byte array (1st byte '\', 2nd byte '0' (0-termination)...

However, since adding CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, I am now getting the (proper) DevicePath... Thanks for the help! ;)